# Parse Custom html in Template Tags, django 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I, inside a custom tag class (template.Node), make the parser render a snippet of html with tags in it?
For example:

```
@register.tag(name='addspam')
class AddSpam(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, parser, token): ...
    def render(self, context):
        spam_html = "SPAM {{ any_tag_here }} SPAM"
        return spam_html
```

Here, AddSpam, when 'called', returns 'SPAM {{ any_tag_here }} SPAM', without rendering the any_tag_here. Thats obviously predictable, but how can I change the return value so that any_tag_here is rendered as if it was 'native'? Are there any methods using the context that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

```
def render(self, context):
    spam_html = "SPAM %(any_tag_here)s SPAM" % context
    return spam_html
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem. I chose another approach: instead of rendering the tags inside the html I'm now doing

```
{% addspam %}
    {{ any_tag_here }}
{% end_addpsam %}
```

that helped the loose coupling of my code, and worked just fine in the particular situation I had.